# To hide the no longer used record instead of deleting it permanently by using PHP and SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a food delivery system for my final year project. For the database, I'm required to hide the record that is no longer in used, instead of deleting the record permanently. For example, if the seller doesn't want to sell a particular meal, they can disable the meal but the record of the meal still available in the database. I need to achieve this by using PHP and SQL. Can someone give me some ideas on how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There could be many approaches but the simplest would be to add a column to the database with either `available` or `unavailable` as the value.

Comment: By having a column that says whether the item is enabled or not

Comment: use a conditional statement against fetched row(s). If it equals something, do something. This, in a nutshell.

Comment: thank you very much for the clues!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The feature you are referring to is something called *soft deletion*.  In soft deletion, a record is logically removed from the database table, without actually removing the record itself.

One common way to implement soft deletion is to add a column which keeps track of whether a column has been soft deleted.  You can use the `TINYINT(1)` type for this purpose.

Your table creation statement would look something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE yourTable (`deleted` TINYINT(1), `col1` varchar, ...)
```

To query out records which have not been logically deleted, you could use:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE deleted <> 1
```

And having a soft delete column also makes it easy to remove stale records if the time comes to do that.

Comment: thank you very much for the details! now i have the ideas how to achieve that

Comment: Please call your column `deleted` or something else more obvious than `sd`

Comment: @mcfedr I was originally going to do that, but then I hesitated since technically the record isn't really deleted.  Then I thought about calling it `soft_deleted` but that seemed too long and clunky, so I ended up using `sd`, which I guess you didn't like.

Comment: It's up to you :) but for the sake of the programmer who will work after you, especially for this, it's very important that *every* access to that table adds the check for soft delete

Answer (score 2):

A extra `deleted` column is a great option in many cases. But you have to be very careful that you *always* check it, and in some cases it can be hard to control this.

Another good choice is a "shadow table" with the same structure, and change your delete process to first copy to the shadow table, and then delete. This means your original table is safe to use, but you cannot do queries on all data (not easily - although `UNION` can help)